# Sharepoint & Excel Services - How to obtain the MDX expression for a cell to be used in a managed UDF?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to access the underling MDX expression for a given cell in a managed UDF executing via Sharepoint/Excel Services?

I am loading excel workbooks to a sharepoint document library then attempting to access these excel workbooks through sharepoint. My problem is that we are using several custom UDF methods that rely on the underlying MDX expression as opposed to just the cell display value. In essence, I think we are trying to determine if it is possible to get our own custom UDF methods to act like the built-in OLAP functions (CubeValue, CubeMember, etc...) that exhibit the behavior described below.

"If a cell reference is used for member_expression, and that cell reference contains a CUBE function, then member_expression uses the MDX expression for the item in the referenced cell, and not the value displayed in that referenced cell."

On the client-side (add-in), we are using some Add-In Express components that allow us to get access to the Range.MDX property but none of that stuff exists on the UDF managed assembly that is pushed to the sharepoint server.

Any guidance that could be shared would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Derek

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem boils down to the fact that the Excel Object Model is not exposed when running Excel Services UDFs on SharePoint. That object model just is not available on the server when the UDFs are executed.

To workaround this behavior, we are going to change our UDFs around so that parameter values are expressed in the full format (MDX / Key Value). This will address the the problems that we are experiencing getting our server-side UDFs to work correctly. The client-side (XLL) UDFs will need to be adapted, as well, given that we will no longer be parsing the values the Key Path from the Range.MDX object.